# How can I run ubuntu and xubuntu in different partitions (as different OS)

Tags: xubuntu

How can I have ubuntu and xubuntu as different os, so that when I turn on my computer I can choose between ubuntu and xubuntu or other ubuntu variant?

Answer (score 1):

It depends on things that you want the two distinct OSes to have in common.

If you want them to have nothing in common, just make two partitions with one flavour of Ubuntu in each partition.

If you want them to have some things in common (typically your personal datas) make partitions where you will mount that shared things in common (`/home` for personal datas) on each flavour (Ubuntu and Xubuntu in your case). However, be careful about shared things. Ensure that things written by Xubuntu won't make Ubuntu crash (or *vice versa*).

PS : why not installing one Ubuntu OS and then install different desktops environments on it (Gnome (already installed with Ubuntu), XFCE--with the `xubuntu-desktop` package, KDE with the `kubuntu-desktop` package if you want to have Kubuntu installed...) ? You can select which one you want when you login.

Comment: how can I install them to have nothing in common? I mean how can I make 2 different partitions... I'm a new ubuntu user :S

Comment: You install one using the advanced install option to use just part of the disk with the partition editor part of the advanced install, then you go back and advanced install the other one, running the partition editor to specify another part of the disk to use for that one. The Ubuntu grub package will give you a choice between them when you boot. You make these decisions in that partition editor. During the first install you will have a chance in the partition editor to set aside a partition for /home.

Comment: how can I install both OSes without deleting the pre existing OS, in my case Windows Xp?

Answer (score 0):

To install Xubuntu alongside Ubuntu, just install a clean install of one OS (erase whole disk), then install the other using the "Install *Ubuntu alongside existing OS" option in the liveCD installer.  The GRUB bootmenu should have an option for either OS when you first boot up.

Comment: An "erase whole disk" install will wipe out any preexisting operating systems installed--which is fine if that's what you want.

Comment: And if I don't want to erase the isntalled OS?